# How to restrict staff unauthorize access to admin page django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created my admin page, so when the admin login it will redirect them to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/, but the admin can change the url to http://127.0.0.1:8000/logistic/ after they login, how to prevent this from happen? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Create a custom permission or group and apply it on the `logistic/` url or view. The admin has not this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to be:
"I do not want the admin to be able to see http://127.0.0.1:8000/logistic/ page"

You can add permission requirements to the `/logistic/` url in a few ways:

1. In your `urls.py` file you can use the `permission_required` decorator (`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required`)
   Example:

```
    url(
        r'logistic/$',
        permission_required("auth.is_internal", raise_exception=True)(
            LogisticClassBasedView.as_view()
        ), name='logistic-page'
    ),
```

`auth.is_internal` can be changed to any permission that an `admin` user does not have.

If `logistic` is a model in your `models.py` file then it will have 4 permission by default (add, change, delete, view I.E. post, put, delete, get). You should have something like `logistic.view_logistic`.

Permissions can be assigned to a `User` or a `Group` in the Django admin panel:
[image: Admin User Permissions]
which corresponds to the following entry in `auth_permission` table:
[image]
which means that you could then check for `customers.view_customer` permission in the `urls.py` file.

To get the `customers` prefix of the permission you need to check the `django_content_type` of your app that corresponds to the `content_type_id` of the screenshot for `id=13`.

If your `logistic` does not have a model in `models.py` this will not work.

Comment: I see, will try your method out and see how it goes